# Multiple key binding in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, keyboard, command

How can i execute some command on, lets say, Ctrl+Shift+E? As i saw we can write the following:

```
KeyBinding kb = new KeyBinding(TestCommand, Key.E, ModifierKeys.Control);
this.InputBindings.Add(kb);
```

But how can i add more ModifierKeys or Keys?

Comment: You can add more keys by calling InputBindings.Add() multiple times.  You can add more modifiers by or-ing them together with |.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ModifiedKeys` is a flags enumeration, so you can combine its values with the logical OR operator (`|`) as follows:

```
KeyBinding kb = new KeyBinding(TestCommand, Key.E, ModifierKeys.Control | ModifierKeys.Shift);
this.InputBindings.Add(kb);
```

Comment: Works :) My fault..I was trying to use the hotkey, that wasn't in binding(Alt instead of Shift)..Stupid mistake. Thank you for the answer.